# How to simulate molecular dynamics in Blender?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I need some effect like rustle or tremble or dynamics. I don't really know what's it in Blender, as I am a beginner. But I wish it could look [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziveAfGp7lY).

If to describe it as a scenario + how and what:

1. Download a molecule from PDB.
2. Open file in PyMol & export the object as .obj file in this ball-and-stick form. Or in any other.
3. Now, till this point I knew what to do. How to make it all tremble like in dynamics? I think it may resemble a cut-wire with lightnings coming from it, you know all such curving.
   [image]

Comment: I have been experimenting with this add on : http://www.blendernation.com/2016/04/28/jigglearmature-add-on/ .... If you can use an armature, it might get you to something like what you want...

Comment: What you show in that video seems to be some basic physics animation. Maybe look into this Molecular Addon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rd4gsO2U6No download linki in the video description, and another video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5QkPnPDcfc

Comment: @rcgauer the key word was really "jiggle", I've found several good videos on jiggling in blender. I will upload the answer soon, so everyone can see, though it's a bit messy, I need to prepare it first)) thx

Comment: Cool... I would be interested to see what you come up with. We work with natural systems and behaviors, and I look forward to seeing your approach.